# Timeline vote summary shows votes for the 24 hours following the timestamp, which is confusing

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, voting, timestamps, timeline

The new timeline is pretty snazzy. But there's one thing I've noticed that's a bit jarring; the timestamp for vote summaries is always 0:00:00 on a particular day, *and the summary covers the rest of that day*. So you end up with a summary that always shows up earlier than the events that presumably triggered the votes that show up in it.

A simple solution is to have it display 23:59:59 instead, and sort accordingly. This way the summary comes in after the events it summarizes.

Comment: Actually it's better to just leave the time field empty, or show "N/A", 23:59:59 will be as confusing, if not even more.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: I don't see why; "vote summary as of the last second of X day" is not that hard to understand. (Special-casing vote summaries to only ever be formatted as dates is not a bad idea either, but in any case the **sorting** should be as though the time were entered as I indicated.)

Comment: `23:59:59` is acceptable if this event already occurred. But for a current day timestamp from the future isn't a good idea. In this case much better is to show a current time of a day for every page refresh.

Comment: @alexolut: I already upvoted the answer that suggested that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am removing the time portion altogether from the display of the daily summary of votes. As a summary of a day, it shouldn't have a time portion at all.

Additionally, I sorted it to the end of the day, given it covers the whole day.

With you in the next build.

Comment: Hmm, seems to be a glitch on SO at least: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/339643/timeline shows either "in 21 hours" (for today's summary) or the full 23:59:59 timestamp if format is switched. I *certainly* don't want the former, and the latter, while not bad, is not what this answer describes.

Comment: Yeah, I never tested with a "today" set of votes, so missed that - also didn't toggle the timestamp when testing.

Comment: Look better now? I've made some changes that should address all of the issues you've raised.

Comment: Yep, looks great!

Comment: Could you also fix [localization issue](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/4329/176217) for `today` item?

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, have it display the current time.
(Or the commonly displayed "just now"/"a few seconds ago"/etc.)

Comment: But that won't fit "summary" any more and IMO will be even more confusing.