# “2 hours ago” in daily summary in votes timeline

Tags: feature-request, bug, voting, timeline

When  I looked at votes timeline list
https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56354356/timeline?filter=WithVoteSummaries
I’ve seen strange order “2 hours ago” after “today”.

```
WHEN TOGGLE FORMAT    WHAT        BY    LICENSE    COMMENT
today        votes    daily summary    N/A        Up: 1 Down: 0
2 hours ago    votes    daily summary    N/A        Up: 1 Down: 0
Jun 6        votes.  daily summary    N/A        Up: 1 Down: 0
```

In toggled format the column make sense.

```
WHEN TOGGLE FORMAT    WHAT        BY    LICENSE    COMMENT
2020-06-11    votes    daily summary    N/A        Up: 1 Down: 0
2020-06-10    votes    daily summary    N/A        Up: 1 Down: 0
2020-06-06    votes    daily summary    N/A        Up: 1
```

I suggest that instead of “2 hours ago” we should see “yesterday”.
It should [“cover the whole day”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/288133/163139)